# When speaking about cache size of a CPU, we only need the size of the cache at the furthest level

Tags: cpu, cache

When speaking about cache size of a CPU, do we only need to know the size of the cache at the furthest level (such as at level 3, when the cache hierachy is 3-level)? Instead of the sum of all the caches at all levels?

This is what I observe from comparing [the output of `lstopo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/interpret-the-output-of-lstopo) and content of `/proc/cpuinfo`. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah... I don't understand your question at all, and I'm pretty sure that's not because I'm drunk.

Comment: I don't get it either and I am probably not drunk. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Please see my previous question about `lstopo`. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/interpret-the-output-of-lstopo

Comment: He's asking about the size of L3 cache, or whatever happens to be the farthest cache away from the CPU, I think.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR;

In general I would say that the cache values that are the most important are the ones closest to the CPU cores. So I generally focus on the L1 & L2 instruction and data caches (i & d). L3 is important but this is highly dependent on the architecture.

To illustrate this point somewhat, I'll cite this article from Anandtech regarding the AMD Athlon 2 vs. the Phenom CPUs. The articled is titled: "[The Athlon II X2 & Phenom II X2: 45nm Dual-Core from AMD](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2775)".

[image: ss of cpus]

[image: ss of table]

But take what I say with a grain of salt. Cache sizing when analyzed this way for figuring out best performance is at best a guess. It's better to do actual performance of an application on a variety of architectures to determine which architectures are better suited to the applications needs/demands!

You can divide up applications into different categories, which can help to gauge roughly how they'll perform. So if you know you're going to be running a long hardware simulation that will be performing a lot of integer computations then CPU speed will be more critical than anything else (in general).

However if you're running a simulation where a massive set of vectors will need to either be read or written to disk as part of this simulation then cache sizing will likely play a key part in getting better performance, at the cost of maybe going with a lower speed CPU.

#### Methods for analyzing a system's L caches

The cache reported in `/proc/cpuinfo` is the size of L3 cache.

```
$ grep "cache size" /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
cache size  : 3072 KB
```

Here's the output of `lstopo`:

[image: ss of lstopo]

#### lshw

As an alternative you can use the command `lshw` to get his information, as well as, the sizes of L1 & L2 too.

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory -sanitize | grep -A 6 "cache:"
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: a
       slot: Internal L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: asynchronous internal write-through data
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: b
       slot: Internal L2 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: burst internal write-through unified
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: c
       slot: Internal L3 Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: burst internal write-back
```

#### cpuid

If you really want to get down to the "brass tacks" of the CPU architecture you can use the tool `cpuid` to query the CPU about intimate details. Here's just a sampling:

```
$ cpuid | grep -E "L1|L2|L3" | head -20
      context ID: adaptive or shared L1 data  = false
      0xdd: L3 cache: 3M, 12-way, 64 byte lines
      0x2c: L1 data cache: 32K, 8-way, 64 byte lines
      0x21: L2 cache: 256K MLC, 8-way, 64 byte lines
      0xca: L2 TLB: 4K, 4-way, 512 entries
      0x09: L1 instruction cache: 32K, 4-way, 64-byte lines
   L1 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/eax):
   L1 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L1 TLB (0x80000005/ebx):
   L1 data cache information (0x80000005/ecx):
   L1 instruction cache information (0x80000005/edx):
   L2 TLB/cache information: 2M/4M pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/eax):
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data associativity        = L2 off (0)
   L2 TLB/cache information: 4K pages & L2 TLB (0x80000006/ebx):
      instruction associativity = L2 off (0)
      data associativity        = L2 off (0)
   L2 unified cache information (0x80000006/ecx):
   L3 cache information (0x80000006/edx):
      associativity         = L2 off (0)
      context ID: adaptive or shared L1 data  = false
   ....
```

This will tell you **A LOT** of information about the types and styles of cache that are used.

Comment: Possible issue: [According to RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-cpuinfo.html), the information about cache size contained in `/proc/cpuinfo` is about L2 cache, not L3 cache. However, this conflicts with [the man page for `lscpu`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lscpu.1.html), as it indicates that is the data shared between all processors (meaning it is L3). Which is correct?