# How to find the page size, associativity, and TLB size and number of entries?

Tags: cache, virtual-memory

Under an Ubuntu system, are there commands for looking up:

- the page size,
- n in n-way cache associativity,
- TLB cache's size and number of entries?

Comment: Look at my other A's to your Q's today. The tool `lshw`.

Comment: @slm: lshw isn't installed on the cluster.

Comment: A computer cluster. Also on my laptop, I can't find what I asked for in the output of lshw.

Comment: Look at some of the output I showed in this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113555/when-speaking-about-cache-size-of-a-cpu-we-only-need-the-size-of-the-cache-at-t

Comment: When I asked about your cluster, I meant what was the underlying OS and cluster technology. There are many "clusters" so it's difficult to tell you what's available w/o more info.

Answer (score 15):

The tool `cpuid` can make a call into the CPU to get more detailed information about the CPU's architecture:

*TLB size, entires, and associativity*

```
$ cpuid | grep -i tlb
   cache and TLB information (2):
      0x5a: data TLB: 2M/4M pages, 4-way, 32 entries
      0x03: data TLB: 4K pages, 4-way, 64 entries
      0x55: instruction TLB: 2M/4M pages, fully, 7 entries
      0xb2: instruction TLB: 4K, 4-way, 64 entries
      0xca: L2 TLB: 4K, 4-way, 512 entries
```

There are various versions of tools called `cpuid` but you want this one, which I believe to be the "original".

- http://www.etallen.com/cpuid.html

The one that comes with Debian/Ubuntu is different, but `cpuid` above can be compiled on other distros if their isn't a pre-built version already available. It's available for most Red Hat based distros in the official repos.