# what is the difference between cpu and core?

Tags: linux, cpu

The output of `lscpu` of my pc looks like --

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 69
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               1200.093
BogoMIPS:              3392.08
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Does it means I have 4 cpus and 2 cores?

Comment: One chip (socket) with two cores that shows up as a total of four CPUs to the system due to hyper-threading.

Comment: @Kusalananda, The `CPU(s)` in the `lscpu` gives the number of logical central processing units (number of `cores` ) in one physical CPU. Isn't it ?

Comment: @saisasanka Yes.  Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88283/so-what-are-logical-cpu-cores-as-opposed-to-physical-cpu-cores

Comment: @saisasanka In this case, there are 4 CPUs and 2 cores in 1 socket. The socket is physical, as are the cores on it. Each core shows as 2 CPUs ("Threads per core").

Comment: CPU(s) = Core(s) per socket * Thread(s) per core

Comment: I like @Kusalananda's explanation, though I would rather use "processor" as a synonym for "chip", as socket is by definition the hole in the motherboard where the processor goes.

Answer (score 11):

From `man lscpu`:

> CPU
>   The logical CPU number of a CPU as used by the Linux kernel.
>
> CORE
>   The logical core number. A core can contain several CPUs.
>
> SOCKET
>   The logical socket number. A socket can contain several cores.

So yes, you have 4 CPUs, contained in physical 2 cores, contained in one physical socket.

You can get the same information from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Related question: [So what are logical cpu cores (as opposed to physical cpu cores)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88283/so-what-are-logical-cpu-cores-as-opposed-to-physical-cpu-cores)

Comment: does it means I can run 4 instruction at a time?

Comment: More or less.  It means it can run 4 tasks in parallel.  See HyperThreading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading

Answer (score 5):

To avoid confusion between logical and physical processors,

> Intel refers to a ***physical processor*** as a ***socket***.

[Hyperthreading](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.resourcemanagement.doc_41/managing_cpu_resources/c_hyperthreading.html) technology allows a single processor core to execute two independent threads simultaneously.

> While hyperthreading does not double the performance of a system, it can increase performance by better utilizing idle resources leading to greater throughput for certain important workload types. An application running on one logical processor of a busy core can expect slightly more than half of the throughput that it obtains while running alone on a non-hyperthreaded processor.

## Summary

- Your system has one physical CPU (Let's name it as X)
- Hyperthreading makes CPU X to behave like two CPUs (CPU - X1 and CPU - X2) but physically not.
- Each X1 and X2 can execute two thread at a time, *simultaneously*

To summarize, you have one physical processor which can execute 4 threads simultaneously.

Comment: "An application running on one logical processor of a busy core can expect slightly more than half of the throughput that it obtains while running alone on a non-hyperthreaded processor". Does this mean that hyperthreading makes a core run at lightly over half its capacity?